# Select last common element in arrays

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, select, unnest

I have a table of commits like this

```
CREATE TABLE commit (
    id            serial PRIMARY KEY,
    parent_commit_ids  INTEGER[] NOT NULL
);
```

Given two commit ids I'm trying to find the latest (furthest to end of array) common parent_commit_id.

Comment: Common to what?  Some data and desired results would help.

Comment: Common to each other. If commit A contains parent_commit_ids=[1,4,5] and commit B contains parent_commit_ids=[1,4,6,8] the latest common parent_commit_id would be 4.

Comment: All previous array elements have to match as well? Or just the last one? Do `[2,3]` and `[1,3]` match on `3`? `[1,2,3,4,5]` and `[6, 4]` match on `4`? Postgres version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one approach using conditional aggregation.

```
select max(x.pid) last_common_id
from commits c
cross join lateral unnest(c.parent_commit_ids) with ordinality x(pid, rn)
where c.id in (1, 2)
group by x.rn
having max(x.pid) filter(where c.id = 1) = max(x.pid) filter(where c.id = 2)
order by rn desc limit 1
```

This assumes that you want to compare commits 1 and 2. The idea is to unnest each array, group by the element index, and then use the `having` clause to filter matching values. You can then sort and select the top match.

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=a0f0889dfc43c14d15d70d97a97c9e7b)**

Sample data (taken from the comments of the question):

```
id | parent_commit_ids
-: | :----------------
 1 | {1,4,6,8}        
 2 | {1,4,5}
```

Results:

```
| last_common_id |
| -------------: |
|              4 |
```

Side note: `commit` is a SQL keyword, hence not a good choice for a table name; I use `commits` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try this if it works for you below is using self join

```
    Select t1.id, max(t2.id) 
    From table t1 join table t2
    on t1.id < t2.id and
    t1.parent_commit_ids = 
      t2.parent_commit_ids 
      Group by t1.id
```